# Negative number is lost using literal notation

Tags: javascript, numbers, negative-number

I'm trying to detect if a number is negative inside a function in Number prototype. And for syntax sugar I am using the ".." to convert the number to an object. But when I evaluate a negative number it turns out to be a positive one:

```
Number.prototype.test = function() {
    n = this.valueOf();
    console.log(n);
    console.log(typeof n);
    return n;
};

-11..test()
// 11 - why???
// number
// -11
```

And if I use the Number object the result is the expected one:

```
Number(-11).test()
// -11
// number
// -11
```

Someone has any idea why is this happening? Thanks. :)

Comment: `..` has probably precedence over the `-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [MDN's Operator Precendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table), the member access operator (`.`) has the second highest priority and unary negation comes at position 5.

As `.` operator has higher priority than unary negation, the expression is actually evaluated like this

```
-(11..test())
```

So, the result of `test` is actually tried to be unary negated. You can confirm that, like this

```
console.log(-11..test());
// -11
```

---

To get the expected result, you need to wrap the number with parenthesis (the operator with the highest precedence), like this

```
(-11).test()
```

Now, the `-11` will be evaluated first, and the `test` is called on the result, which is `-11` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unary minus, as an operator, has lower precedence than `.`.

```
(-11).test();
```